# Data structure for categories and tags

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am building a business directory, where users can create listings for their business. The structure of the directory is as follows:

- There are Categories and Tags
- A Category can have many Tags. A Tag can only belong to one Category
- Listings are assigned to Categories and Category Tags

The current data structure is as follows:

```
category               tag
============           ===========
id                     id
name                   name
                       category_id (FK)


listing                listing_category           listing_category_tag
============           ================           ====================
id                     id                         listing_category_id (FK)
name                   listing_id (FK)            tag_id (FK)
etc                    category_id (FK)
```

As the directory builds up, I will inevitably be looking to add new categories and tags, and existing ones will probably have to be archived. This may mean that some listings will need to be updated to reference newly created categories and tags.

Is this data structure set up efficiently to handle situations like this? I want to avoid situations whereby listings have tags that don't match the current category assignments.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain consistency in database level, I will suggest using natural composite primary keys instead of surrogate identifiers in your junction tables:

```
category               tag
============           ================
id     (PK)             name        (PK)(UC)             
name   (UC)             category_id (PK)(FK)


listing               listing_category           listing_category_tag
============          ================           ====================
id   (PK)             category_id(FK)(PK)        listing_category.PK (FK)
name (UC)             listing_id (FK)(PK)        tag.PK (FK)
etc
```

We will end up something like this:

```
listing_category_tag
====================
listing_category_category_id (FK)
listing_category_listing_id(FK)
tag_name(FK)
tag_category_id(FK)
```

Now having check constraints like

```
check_constraint_1 = {listing_category_category_id = tag_category_id}
```

Will prevent inconsistancy

Comment: Agree to this suggestion, you can also setup a MySQL View for the tables listing_category and listing_category_tag. The view will automatically populate as the source tables are being populated, this can be applied or not depending on you preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

The design that you presented is reasonable.  I'll list a few grey areas here, not so much to challenge your approach as to provoke thought:

- listing_category references category.  tag also references category.  listing_category_tag references tag and listing category, so if referential integrity isn't maintained you could have a listing_category_tag which references a listing which is associated with a different category from the tag category.  I think this shows the design isn't in [Boyce-Codd Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form) but perhaps it's 3rd Normal?
- As you described the possibility of changing categories and tags over time, this could snowball into a mess of referential dependencies.  I know it sounds great in theory, but in actual practice, it's very easy for small mistakes to compound when the design permits referential inconsistencies. (And yes, constraints, but again, in actual practice, this is the sort of thing that can easily go off the rails.)

Have you considered a simpler and more de-normalized approach? This is becoming much more common and is widely used on some very large and successful sites.  For example:

```
listing           listing_category_tag
==========        ====================
id                listing_id
name              category_name 
etc.              tag_name
```

Put a composite index on listing_category_tag with (category_name, tag_name).  When you want a list of categories, just `select distinct(category_name)` and when you want a list of unique tags for one category, `select distinct(tag_name) where category=?`

You may be surprised at how well this will perform with even millions of listings and how much simpler and less prone to errors this will be to implement and maintain.

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure looks great for the challenge you're attempting to solve.

> This may mean that some listings will need to be updated to reference newly created categories and tags...
>
> I want to avoid situations whereby listings have tags that don't match the current category assignments.

This may be achieved in a a couple of different ways.

- You can handle the referential integrity from the business logic layer in the application code, leaving the database agnostic.
- You can enforce referential integrity in the database on the foreign keys.

If you choose the first method, then nothing needs to be done on the model you have already. When you update or insert new listings / tags / categories the application code has to make sure that they are valid.

If you choose the second method, then change the foreign key in `listing_category_tag` to a compound foreign key, and specify the appropriate constraints.

```
listing_category_tag
====================
listing_category_id (FK: listing_category)       
tag_id (FK: tag)
category_id (FK: tag)
```

[The MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) has good examples of how to use Constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design, while it enforces the inclusion constraint that all assigned tags must have the same category as the listing, is unnessearily complex. A simpler, and more natural, design, which also enforces the inclusion constraint, is the following

```
category               tag
============           ===========
id                     category_id (FK)
name                   name
                       PK( category_id, name)

listing                listing_category           listing_tag
============           ================           ====================
id                     listing_id (FK)            listing_id (FK)
name                   category_id (FK)           category_id (FK)    
etc                                               tag_name (FK)
```